# How to save newly shuffled task list to db.json in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

This is my **db.json** file

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Doctors Appointment",
      "day": "May 5th at 2:30pm",
      "reminder": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Meeting at School",
      "day": "May 6th at 10:30pm",
      "reminder": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Food Shopping",
      "day": "May 7th at 12:30pm",
      "reminder": false
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "text": "Jogging",
      "day": "May 8th at 4:30pm",
      "reminder": true
    },
    {
      "text": "Test Task",
      "day": "May 9th at 11:30pm",
      "reminder": false,
      "id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Below shown is the **tasks.component.html**

```
<app-add-task (on_add_task)="add_task($event)"></app-add-task>
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop_task($event)">
    <app-task-item *ngFor="let task of tasks" [task]="task" (on_delete_task)="delete_task(task)" (on_toggle_reminder)="toggle_reminder(task)" cdkDrag></app-task-item>
</div>
```

The next one is **tasks.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from "../../services/task.service";
import { Task } from "../../Task";
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tasks',
  templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {
  tasks: Task[] = []
  name: any;

  constructor(private task_service: TaskService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.task_service.get_tasks().subscribe((tasks) => (this.tasks = tasks));
  }

  delete_task(task: Task) {
    this.task_service.delete_task(task).subscribe(() => (this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(t => t.id !== task.id)));
  }

  toggle_reminder(task: Task) {
    task.reminder = !task.reminder;
    this.task_service.update_task_reminder(task).subscribe()
  }

  add_task(task: Task) {
    this.task_service.add_task(task).subscribe((task) => (this.tasks.push(task)));
  }

  drop_task(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.tasks, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    // this.name = this.tasks[event.currentIndex];
    // console.log(this.name.text);
    console.log(this.tasks)
  } 
}
```

Below shown is **task.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Task } from "../Task";

const http_options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {
  private api_url = 'http://localhost:5000/tasks'

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  get_tasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get<Task[]>(this.api_url)
  }

  delete_task(task: Task): Observable<Task> {
    const url = `${this.api_url}/${task.id}`;
    return this.http.delete<Task>(url);
  }

  update_task_reminder(task: Task): Observable<Task> {
    const url = `${this.api_url}/${task.id}`;
    return this.http.put<Task>(url, task, http_options);
  }

  add_task(task: Task): Observable<Task> {
    return this.http.post<Task>(this.api_url, task, http_options)
  }
}
```

The next one is **task-item.component.html**

```
<div [ngClass]="{ reminder: task.reminder}" class="task" (dblclick)="on_toggle(task)">
    <h3>{{ task.text }} <fa-icon (click)="on_delete(task)" [ngStyle]="{color:'red'}" [icon]="faTimes"></fa-icon></h3>
    <p>{{task.day}}</p>
</div>
```

The last one is **task-item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from "../../Task";
import { faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-item',
  templateUrl: './task-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-item.component.css']
})
export class TaskItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() task!: Task;
  @Output() on_delete_task: EventEmitter<Task> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() on_toggle_reminder: EventEmitter<Task> = new EventEmitter();
  faTimes = faTimes;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  on_delete(task: any){
    this.on_delete_task.emit(task);
  }

  on_toggle(task: any){
    this.on_toggle_reminder.emit(task);
  }
  }
```

Everything works with the Angular CDK drag-drop. I can shuffle my tasks. But I want to keep the shuffled list as it is. How can I update the whole db.json with the new shuffled order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you cannot edit db.json directly in angular, you have to do it on the server.
follow the route of update_task_reminder, delete_task and add_task on your server and there you should edit (write) in your db.json.

so if you are using node.js you should post a new question about that and post your node code.